Dropdown is not working using ASP.NET Core MVC
_Layout.cshtml:
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
</head>
<body>
    @if (HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.GetString("IsLoggedIn") == null)
    {
        <partial name="_NavBarBlank" />
    }
    else
    {
        <partial name="_NavigationBar" />
    }

    // code

    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</body>

In _NavigationBar.cshtml:
@inject IHttpContextAccessor HttpContextAccessor
@{
    SQLDB sQLDB = new SQLDB();
}
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">YourAppName</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <!-- Home link -->
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            @using Newtonsoft.Json;
            @inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IHttpContextAccessor HttpContextAccessor

            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                @{
                    string Role = HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.GetString("Role");
                    var dataTableParent = sQLDB.CreateTable($"SELECT Controller, isDropdown FROM WMS_ParentNavbar WHERE ROLE = "+Role+" ORDER BY Priority ASC");

                }

                @foreach (DataRow drParent in dataTableParent.Rows)
                {
                    string controller = drParent["Controller"].ToString();
                    bool isDropdown = Convert.ToBoolean(drParent["isDropdown"]);
                    var dataTableChild = sQLDB.CreateTable($"SELECT  CN.Views  FROM WMS_ParentNavbar PN  INNER JOIN WMS_ChildNavbar CN on  PN.ObjectID = CN.ObjectID  WHERE  CN.Controller = '" + controller + "' AND CN.Role = "+ Role );



                    <li class="nav-item @(isDropdown? "dropdown" : "")">
                        @if (!isDropdown)
                        {
                            <a class="nav-link" asp-controller="@controller" asp-action="Index">@controller</a>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                        
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="@controller" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                                @controller
                            </a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="@controller">
                                @foreach (DataRow drChild in dataTableChild.Rows)
                                {
                                    string viewName = drChild["Views"].ToString();
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" asp-controller="@controller" asp-action="@viewName">@viewName</a>
                                }
                            </div>
                        }
                    </li>
                }
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>


In ASP.NET Core MVC: the target is I want to dynamic my navigation bar based on the role of the account then the role will pass the query the first query will return the parent which the controller then next the second query to get the child of the parent which is the views. Now, in my problem the dropdown is not working can't dropdown the child.
In the image attached there is a child. This concern only is the dropdown is not working.

Can anyone can help with my problem?

The issue might be related to the Bootstrap Version.
From your code, you are using data-bs-toggle and data-bs-target attributes, which belongs to the Bootstrap 5, so, if you are using the bootstrap 4 js and css reference, they will not be working.
I checked your code with Bootstrap 5, the code works well:

You can open the bootstrap css and js file to check the version.

To solve this problem, you can upgrade the Bootstrap version to the Bootstrap 5, or use the following reference:
   <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

If you want to use Bootstrap 4 version, you need to change the related attributes to data-toggle or data-target. More detail information about Bootstrap 4, you can check this link.
